# How to change my .htaccess to access serviceworker file from root

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router, service-worker

To make react router work i changed the .htacsess and added the code below :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

then added this line

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sw\.js$
```

to make it exclude sw.js but it doesn't seem to exclude sw.js and requesting domain.com/sw.js still serves the index.html

here is my full .htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sw\.js$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` string starts with a leading `/` . You need to add a slash to the condition pattern

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sw\.js$
```

Comment: tried that and didn't work either then i removed / for testing

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri this should work if both `js` and `htaccess` files are located in the same directory.

Comment: found the issue, parent folder was also modifying sw.js file and that caused the problem.

Comment: You last voted on this answer 19 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited. 
edit your answer so i can upvote it